# How to add new contact in Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a new contact containing one or more phone number and email address, a street address, an organisation name, and a bitmap image, then add it to the user's contact list.

I want the system to handle the saving of the contact so I don't have to deal with permissions.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to add new contact for contact list your application have to has permissions for that. [Example](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-contacts-programatically-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/)

Comment: have u searched this on google or on stack overflow

Comment: here he is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520499/android-intent-action-action-insert-or-edit-should-it-be-used-for-adding-con

Comment: @Gaurav, I must have missed that one! Do you know how to add the image though?

Comment: @sticks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423642/add-contact-photo-in-android many solution are available search it on google buddy you will get the solution